# Right padding on nested chat quotes causes premature word wrapping

Tags: bug, design, chat

When there is a long series of nested quotes in the chat, the right padding on each quote accumulates, leaving lots of unused whitespace on the right side of the screen and premature word wrapping. The offending CSS appears to be:

```
.ob-wikipedia, .ob-amazon, .ob-gist, .ob-message, .ob-lpadbug, .ob-manpage, .ob-blog, .ob-exception, .ob-anime, .ob-github {

    padding: 0.8em 1.5em;
    background-color: White;
    color: #222;

}
```

Adjusting that to:

```
.ob-wikipedia, .ob-amazon, .ob-gist, .ob-message, .ob-lpadbug, .ob-manpage, .ob-blog, .ob-exception, .ob-anime, .ob-github {

    padding: 0.8em 0.1em 0.8em 1.5em;
    background-color: White;
    color: #222;

}
```

avoids early word wrapping. Note, I have not tested this in other parts of the site to see if anything else breaks.

Here's an [example of the breaking behavior](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50358244#50358244):

[image: Chat word wrap]

Comment: This seems to be one of those, “Doctor, it hurts when I do this” problems, where the answer is, of course, don’t create extremely deeply-nested blocks of quotes. It’s hard to imagine what a useful application of this would be.

Comment: @CodyGray You're probably right this it's not necessarily useful, but I have run into this in a private chat (mod humor is only borderline useful). If the CSS wasn't an easy fix, our answer was that I needed a bigger monitor.

Comment: Oh, mod humor is the worst!

Comment: Now I'm curious as to why there's a css class for Anime